# JSON error when invoking an Alexa Skill example request within AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to follow along with a youtube video tutorial that teaches you how to build a simple alexa skill in C#. The video is old, and some stuff is deprecated. one of the most recent comments says that in Visual Studio 2019, you have to change a line of code to
`[assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]`

So right now my function looks like this:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Alexa.NET.Request;
using Alexa.NET.Request.Type;
using Alexa.NET.Response;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
namespace LambdaAlexa
{
    public class Function
    {

        public const string INVOCATION_NAME = "Country Info";

        public SkillResponse FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
        {

            var requestType = input.GetRequestType();
            if (requestType == typeof(IntentRequest))
            {
                return MakeSkillResponse(
                        $"Hello Infotec! This is the first response from your Alexa skill using c sharp.",
                        true);
            }
            else
            {
                return MakeSkillResponse(
                        $"I don't know how to handle this intent. Please say something like Alexa, ask {INVOCATION_NAME} about Canada.",
                        true);
            }
        }


        private SkillResponse MakeSkillResponse(string outputSpeech,
            bool shouldEndSession,
            string repromptText = "Just say, tell me about Canada to learn more. To exit, say, exit.")
        {
            var response = new ResponseBody
            {
                ShouldEndSession = shouldEndSession,
                OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech { Text = outputSpeech }
            };

            if (repromptText != null)
            {
                response.Reprompt = new Reprompt() { OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech() { Text = repromptText } };
            }

            var skillResponse = new SkillResponse
            {
                Response = response,
                Version = "1.0"
            };
            return skillResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

and i'm trying to invoke the MyColorIs example request after I upload the function, but for some reason im getting this response.

```
{
  "errorType": "JsonSerializerException",
  "errorMessage": "Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Alexa.NET.Request.SkillRequest: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'Alexa.NET.Request.Type.Request'",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ],
  "cause":   {
    "errorType": "NotSupportedException",
    "errorMessage": "Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'Alexa.NET.Request.Type.Request'",
    "stackTrace": [
      "at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_DeserializeCreateObjectDelegateIsNull(Type invalidType)",
      "at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleStartObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)",
      "at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)",
      "at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)",
      "at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ParseCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)",
      "at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)",
      "at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here? I've googled the error but not a ton of useful information comes up, and i'm pretty stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install the `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json` package via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json/) and replace

```
[assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
```

with

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializerAttribute(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
```